# Symfony4 Doctrine Associations insert

Tags: doctrine-orm, associations, symfony4

I get xml data from external soap server, parsing data and create Object. Next I want to persist it in database but it does't work.

Company id, I get from external soap and its string unique value like `387sdfh899ohkadkfh8`.

**Company**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Address", mappedBy="company", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $addresses;

    // ...
}
```

**Address**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company",inversedBy="adresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $company;

    // ...
}
```

**CompanyController**

```
class CompanyController
{
    // ...

    $json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');
    $obj = $serializer->deserialize($json, 'array<App\Entity\Company>', 'json');     

    // ...
}
```

Every thing looks as expected. Object was created including two Address objects.

## Update - begin

This is structure what I get from deserialize

```
array:1 [
  0 => Company {#524
    -id: "0946346d06ffe3f551a80700c2a5c534"
    // ..
    -addresses: ArrayCollection {#538
      -elements: array:2 [
        0 => Address {#1017
          -id: null
            // ...
          -company: null
        }
        1 => Address {#537
          -id: null
              // ..
          -company: null
        }
      ]
    }
    -status: "Active"
  }
]
```

## Update - end

But when I try to store it in database:

**CompanyController**

```
class CompanyController
{
    // ...

    $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    foreach ($obj as $o) $em->persist($o);
    $em->flush();

    // ...
}
```

I'm getting error

> inserting address doesn't include id of company. company_id is setting to `null`

Similar json data, including addresses corresponding to company I'll be getting from client with json format, parsing it via FormType and store to database but I can't manage with :/

How should I insert that related objects in proper way?

Comment: Not sure what deserializer are you using, but are you sure it's calling your `addAddress`/`setCompany` methods?

Comment: I use JMSSerializer, and truly speaking I don't know if it calls `addAddress / setCompany` and I don't know how to check it

Comment: according to Your suggestion I added `@JMS\Accessor(setter="addAddress")` and really addAddres wasn't called previously. Now i get error `Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Company::addAddress() must be an instance of App\Entity\Address, instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given`.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer, not part of your question

Comment: @Trix ok, thaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok, I solved the problem**

**Company**

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Address", mappedBy="company", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @JMS\Accessor(setter="setAddresses")
     */
    private $addresses;
```

And added method:

```
/**
 * @param ArrayCollection $addresses
 * @return Company
 */
public function setAddresses(ArrayCollection $addresses): self
{
    if ( !$this->addresses instanceof ArrayCollection ){
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    };

    foreach ($addresses as $address){
        if (!$this->addresses->contains($address)) {
        $this->addresses[] = $address;
        $address->setCompany($this);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I spend on this issue two days :/ and solution was so easy, **@malarzm** Thanks for suggestion it helped me a lot.